# Composing dynamic SELECT Statement

Tags: mysql, select

Some advise on this issue:

```
select
    concat(MySourceTable,',',sid,'X',gid,'X',qid) as MySourceFieldname
from
    MySchemaTable
where
    SomeCriteria;
```

Using the upper Statement I get a list (one column only) of fieldnames.
How can I transform this to be shown in horizontal (Fields next to each other) position, separated by comma
I want to produce a 'normal" SELECT-Statement for further use.

@amixdon
Input is :

```
select concat('shape_survey_990113',sid,'X',gid,'X',qid) as lsfield -- <=MySourceFieldname
 from shape_questions -- <=MySchemaTable i.e. kind of dictionary
where question='result' -- <=SomeCriteria
  and sid=990113
  and language='en'
  order by lsfield;
```

Result of Input looks like this (e.g.)

```
lsfields
---------
shape_survey_990113.990113X468X729,
shape_survey_990113.990113X469X733,
shape_survey_990113.990113X470X737,
....,
```

Explanation: sid, gid, qid are numeric contents taken from a table that is comparable to a dictionary. This is the source system which I want to select information from (cannot be changed). It is an opensource survey tool. Within this table all information for each survey is handled (numeric value 990113 is identifiying one special survey out of many. The concat above ist the final field name that holds the answers to the questions.
The 'shape_survey_990113' is the table to select the firlds from:

This select result should look like this an can be written to some variable
(e.g. SET @MyFields =...)

```
shape_survey_990113.990113X235X476, shape_survey_990113.990113X235X484, shape_survey_990113.990113X235X496
```

..to be used in the next step to make up a real select statement like:

```
concat('SELECT ', @MyFields, ' FROM shape_survey_991103;')
```

Unfortunately i cannot upload a screenshot fort this, not enough reputation....

Comment: Can you show example data and expected result?

Comment: just use group_concat around what you already have

Comment: please also post some sample input and the desired output

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing sacred, and quite a bit profane, about that `CONCAT()`. Lose it. And lose the quoted commas.  Like so.

```
select
    MySourceTable, sid, gid, qid
from
    MySchemaTable
where
    SomeCriteria;
```

Simple as can be.

Comment: i dont think this is what the op is asking. the last sentence is : ... want to produce a 'normal' select-statement for further use..

Comment: @amdixon feel free to edit "my"  answer -- it's community wiki so it's "our" answer.

Comment: will do when the user clarifies the desired input+output